# How do I display the numbers that belong to the positive,negative,odd and even groups?

Tags: java, arrays

This program asks for 10 integer numbers and stores these integer numbers in an array.
The program then counts how many odd, how many even, how many negative, how many positive, and how many zero numbers. The program should also display what are the numbers that belong in these groups.

this is my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class count { 
public static void main (String[] args)
        {           
            int i,x,a[] = new int[10];          
            int n=0,p=0,e=0,o=0,z=0;            
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.println("Enter 10 Numbers");         
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
             System.out.println("Enter Number :");
             a[i] = input.nextInt();
            }           
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                if(a[i]<0)
                    n++;
                else
                    p++;

                x=a[i]%2;
                if(x==0)
                    e++;
                else
                    o++;
                                if(a[i]==0)
                                    z++;
            }

            //print
            System.out.println("Total Even Numbers = "+e);
                        System.out.println("Even Numbers are = ");
            System.out.println("Total Odd Numbers = "+o);
                         System.out.println("Odd Numbers are = ");
            System.out.println("Total Negative Numbers = "+n);
                         System.out.println("Negative Numbers are = ");
            System.out.println("Total Positive Numbers = "+p);
                         System.out.println("Positive Numbers are = ");
                        System.out.println("Total Zero Numbers = "+z);
        }
}
```

---

This is the output of it.

```
Enter 10 Numbers
Enter Number :
0
Enter Number :
0
Enter Number :
2
Enter Number :
-3
Enter Number :
-4
Enter Number :
6
Enter Number :
9
Enter Number :
5
Enter Number :
0
Enter Number :
9
Total Even Numbers = 6
Even Numbers are = 
Total Odd Numbers = 4
Odd Numbers are = 
Total Negative Numbers = 2
Negative Numbers are = 
Total Positive Numbers = 8
Positive Numbers are = 
Total Zero Numbers = 3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Okay - so how does it not do what you want? You've shown us the code (and that's a great start, btw - so many questions just ask us to do the work) but you haven't told us what happens when you run it, vs what you'd expect to happen.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly recommend getting an IDE or similar to format your code for you - it's much easier to read when it's all consistently indented etc. (I'd also suggest using braces even for single-statement `if` bodies etc, but that's another step.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe that his issue is this `what are the numbers that belong in these groups`. So he managed to calculate the number of each group, but now he wants to find the exact numbers that belong to each group.

Comment: A simple solution is to create an array or better a list for each group and then you will have your numbers grouped.

Comment: @Aris: That may well be the case - but the OP should put that in their question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed, he/she should clarify their issue

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments a simple solution will be to save every number to the corresponding [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
List<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then every time you check each number with the `if` statements instead of having a counter just add the number to the list

```
if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) evenNumbers.add(numbers[i]);
```

And last print them as you already do but check the size of each `List`

```
System.out.println("Total Even Numbers = " + evenNumbers.size());
System.out.println("Even Numbers are = " + evenNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class countPZN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        int p = 0, o=0;
        int z = 0, e=0;
        int num []  = new int[7];
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the number " + (i + 1));
            num[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <7; i++) {
            if (num[i] < 0) 
                n++;
            
            else if(num[i]>0)
                p++;
            else if(num[i]==0)
                z++;
            else if(num[i]%2==0)
                e++;
            else 
                o++;
        }
            System.out.println("Number of negative number is " + n);
            System.out.println("Number of positive number is " + p);
            System.out.println("number of zero number is " + n);
            System.out.println("number of even number is " + e );
            System.out.println("number of odd number is " + o );
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).